# reload page when clicking on current page link, using jQuery Address plugin

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery Address plugin, and all my ajax navigation is based on it, and more precisely on internalChange or externalChange events like that

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    initDeepLinking();
});

function linkClicked(e){        
    var request = $.ajax({
          url: e.path,
          data: e.queryString,
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "json",
    });

    request.done(handleResponse);
    return false;    
}

function handleResponse(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    $('#main').html(response.responseText);
};

function initDeepLinking(){
    $.address.internalChange(function(event){
        linkClicked(event);
    });
    $.address.externalChange(function(event){
        linkClicked(event);
    });
}
```

so when i click on a link leading to the current page, nothing happens.
I would like the page to reload when I do that. Any simple options ?
Thanks !

Comment: the code you provided does not tell us much. can you provide link to your full js code?

Answer (score 1):

I am having troubles understanding what your question really is:

- you don't know how to attach a handler to the link
- you don't know what statement can be used to refresh the current page

In order to set a handler you can use some selector. For example, getting the element by class. [More about jquery selectors here.](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

After you have the element, you can attach an [event handler](http://api.jquery.com/category/Events/) for the ['on click' event](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and do something like this:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Comment: Maybe that this would be the only way... but i was hoping for a built in listeners in the Address plugin for that.